# Which *_cast should I use to cast an arbitrary integer-type pointer to a char pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I need to fill an integer-type variable (of arbitrary size) with data from */dev/urandom*. With that in mind, I have the following piece of code:

```
std::fstream fstr("/dev/urandom", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
fstr.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&randomseed), sizeof(randomseed));
fstr.close();
```

(*randomseed* is the variable which I need to fill with random data).

Will this do the right thing (i.e. is it safe regardless of library implementation), or should I use some other *_cast?

Comment: You've chosen the right cast, this is a `reinterpret_cast`, but don't forget about error handling, check the error flags of the stream object after reading.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Of course, I just didn't want to include that in the code snippet for the sake of brevity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's NOT safe. Only the `char` types are guaranteed to have no trap representations.

The "proper" solution is to wrap `/dev/urandom` in a C++ `<random>` engine, and use a `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: How exactly do I wrap `/dev/random` in a `<random>` engine? I mean, I understand that what I'm doing here is "hacky", but doesn't the `<random>` engine implementation itself have to have a similar "hack" at some point? Would a safer solution be to not use `istream::read` and use `istream::get` instead to get one byte at a time out of `/dev/random`?

Comment: @Veeno: Existing engines are exempt from most UB rules because they're considered part of the implementation and may rely on other parts of the implementation. That said, you can certainly read 4 bytes at a time and put them in an `unsigned long` - just shift the second byte by 8, the third by 16 and the fourth by 24 bits. Since the operations are numeric and within range of the type, you don't have trap issues. Sure, this may leave some bits zero, but that's not a problem for a random engine. The distribution will take care of that, using the min/max values of the random engine.

Comment: Hm... Why can I read four bytes at a time out of `/dev/urandom` but not one? :( Doesn't reading one `char` mean reading just one byte? I could read four bytes `sizeof(randomseed)` times, bitwise XOR each four bytes to a single byte, shift accordingly and fill the variable `randomseed` with random data that way, but that seems awfully wasteful - I would rather only read as much data out of `/dev/urandom` as I need.

Comment: Eh, you're really not getting it I'm afraid. You can read one, it's just not very random (only 256 possibilities). Also, you seem very stuck on `sizeof(randomseed)` but that's a pointless number. Doesn't tell you the allowed range of values. For that, you have `std::numeric_limits`, which you can then use to pick a proper `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: Well, I am "stuck" on `sizeof(randomseed)` because that tells me exactly how many bytes I need to read out of `/dev/urandom` to fill the entire `randomseed` with random data... Yes, one byte is only 256 possibilities, I know that, but if I read four bytes that's still 256^4 = 2^32 possibilities, regardless if I read them one at a time or all four at once.

Comment: @Veeno: No, `sizeof(randomseed)` just isn't. Example: `sizeof(randomseed)` is 4, allowed values are -2147483647 to +2147483647 and all-ones is a trap value. There are 2^32-1 allowed values.

Comment: Which integral type has all-ones as a trap value? I mean, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types) it clearly says that all integral types have value ranges either from -2^(n-1) to 2^(n-1)-1, or from 0 to 2^n-1, i.e. covering all possible 2^n allowed values.